"в какой точке"
I am unsure about the meaning of "в какой точке" (absolutely, I mean: when it is not followed by a substantive in the genitive). In Викисловарь we have this meaning for точка:


место организации или ведения чего-либо, место, где расположено, установлено что-либо ◆ торговая точка, точка сбора, огневая точка


Thus I would understand it as "в каком месте" ("in which place"). But my doubt comes from:

Но в толпе, недалеко от того места, где он сидел, откуда-то сбоку — он бы никак не указал, в каком именно месте и в какой точке, — мелькнуло одно лицо, бледное лицо, с курчавыми темными волосами, с знакомыми, очень знакомыми улыбкой и взглядом, — мелькнуло и исчезло.

(Идиот by Dostoevsky). We already have "в каком именно месте", thus "и в какой точке" would be redundant and I thought it should mean something different (maybe "in which moment"?).

This is indeed a redundancy of sorts.
The scene you are referring to happens inside a concert hall. In that context "место" can mean "a seat", as in: "место 1А" -- "seat 1A". Perhaps by "в каком именно месте1" the author meant "in what seat" and by "в какой точке", "in what part of the hall", thus referring to the same location with slightly different levels of precision.

1 - This is archaic; in modern Russian we say "на каком месте".

Thank you! When you write "in modern Russian we say "на каком месте"." you mean: when we mean "in which seat", right? If we mean "in which place" (где - without referring to a seat), is it "в каком месте" or "на каком месте"?

Yes, today "на каком месте" is "in which seat"; "в каком месте" == "in which/what place"
